# How to tell the protocol/type of storage drives?

Tags: linux, nfs, iscsi

I'm sorry if this is question is badly formed -- I am really struggling with the topic of storage devices.

Say I log into a random linux machine. It has several attached drives listed in df -h.

I haven't yet come up with a good way to determine if these drives are using iscsi, fc (fcp), RDM, or even if they are physical cards?

So far the method I've come up with is checking for each protocol individually. So, first, I check fstab for nfs. Then I check iscsiadm -m session -o show for iscsi connections. Then check lspci looking for something that looks like a physical card, and no idea how to check for fc or rdm.

This is not a good way to do it. Is there a better way?